# Postgresql full text match unexpected

Tags: postgresql

Looking at the following queries:

```
1. select to_tsvector('xyz-abc-testbed') @@ to_tsquery('abc')  # true
2. select to_tsvector('xyz/xyz-abc-testbed') @@ to_tsquery('abc')  # false
```

Then I realized that:

```
select to_tsvector('xyz-abc-testbed')
   to_tsvector
----------------------------------------------
'abc':3 'testb':4 'xyz':2 'xyz-abc-testb':1
```

But

```
select to_tsvector('xyz/xyz-abc-testbed')
   to_tsvector
----------------------------------------------
'xyz/xyz-abc-testbed':1
```

Looks like "/" impacts result of to_tsvector very much. But I don't find an explanation in PG documentation.

Please explain how '/' impacts tv_tsvector or point out some documentation that explains that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: to_tsvector tries to guess what the mess you  feed it means. splitting words, converting plurals etc.  if you just want a to do substring match use regex instead. (and pg_trgm index for speed)

Comment: I'm trying to do full text search. I just abstracted my problem to a simple model.

Comment: why do you consider the substring 'abc' to be a word in your second example.  to me it looks like a fragment of a filename.

Comment: I don't think it's matter of English word. 'abc' is just a sample, even if we replace 'abc' with 'hello' in sample 2, result will still be false.

Answer (score 4):

The first step in full-text search processing is the *parser*, which splits the string in tokens and uses a heuristics to assign a type to them. Further processing depends on the type.

The function `ts_debug` is useful to analyze what is going on:

```
SELECT alias, description, lexemes
FROM ts_debug('xyz/xyz-abc-testbed');

 alias |    description    |        lexemes        
-------+-------------------+-----------------------
 file  | File or path name | {xyz/xyz-abc-testbed}
(1 row)

SELECT alias, description, lexemes
FROM ts_debug('xyz-abc-testbed');

      alias      |           description           |      lexemes      
-----------------+---------------------------------+-------------------
 asciihword      | Hyphenated word, all ASCII      | {xyz-abc-testbed}
 hword_asciipart | Hyphenated word part, all ASCII | {xyz}
 blank           | Space symbols                   | 
 hword_asciipart | Hyphenated word part, all ASCII | {abc}
 blank           | Space symbols                   | 
 hword_asciipart | Hyphenated word part, all ASCII | {testbed}
(6 rows)
```

PostgreSQL interprets a string with `/` in it as file path. It will not split a file path in parts, like it does with hyphenated words.